# Sum of binary numbers in C++ and overflow bit?

Tags: c++, arrays, binary, numbers, sum

I need help with adding the 16 bits that are concatenated in 'bits'. Every time a set of 16 bits is concatenated, I want them to be added (binary addition) to an array...till all sets of 16 are complete in my string. If there is an overflow, length of final sum >16...then add that extra bit to the final sum as 0000000000000001 (where 1 is the 16th bit).

For a string entered: "hello"

```
std::vector<std::string> bitvec;
std::string bits;
for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); i += 2) {
    bits = std::bitset<8>(s[i]).to_string() + std::bitset<8>(s[i + 1]).to_string();
    bitvec.push_back(bits);
}
```

Comment: I don't get it. What do you want your code to do?

Comment: i want to add bits to an array such that each time the for loop runs the 'bits' part in the code is added to the array (zero initially). and then the next 'bits' get added to the same array, till i get the final sum. array = array + bits; but the addition is binary so i cant do it this way using + operator.

Comment: Are you saying the + operator does non-binary addition?  So far, what you're describing can be summed up generally as: `int value = 0; // loop... value += s[i] << 8 + s[i + 1]`, or something similar

Comment: @user899714 So you want `bitvec` to have length 1 and contain as the sole element the binary representation of the sum of the summands that come from `bits` ?

Comment: "every time a set of 16 bits is concatenated, i want them to be added (binary addition) to an array" - doesn't make sense; you can't add to an array using binary addition (unless the array itself represents a number, in which case, please be clear on the representation)? I don't even see an array in your code unless you're talking about the vector. Please give some complete examples of input and desired output.

Comment: You are not doing any binary addition there. All you are doing is pushing strings to a vector.

Comment: You are concatenating strings, not performing binary addition.

Comment: @adrian panasiuk: No, not really. please read the comments to/by  Ashelly below.

Comment: i am not doing any addition yet, but i want to and thats what i dont know. how to.

Comment: apologies for being so unclear in my post. but i was just very confused when i posted that.

Answer (score 0):

Possible problems:

If `s` holds `"hello"`, then `std::bitset<8>(s[i])` will be 0.  You need to pass a string containing only "1"s and "0"s to the [bitset constructor](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/bitset/bitset/bitset/)

Once your bitsets are initialized properly, you can't add them together by using the `to_string()` function, that will just concatenate the representations:  `"1011" + "1100"` will become `"10111100"`

Oh, wait, maybe that's what you do want.
It sort of sounds like you are inventing a complicated way to sum the pairs of ascii values interpreted as 16 bit numbers, but it's not clear.  Your code is roughly equivalent to  something like:

```
std::vector<uint16_t> bitvec;
unsigned char* cp = s.c_str()+1;
while (*cp) {
   uint16_t bits = *(cp-1)>>8 + *(cp);
   bitvec.push_back(bits);
}
//sum over the numbers contained in bitvec here?

uint32_t sum=0;

for(std::vector<int16_t>::iterator j=bitvec.begin();j!=bitvec.end();++j) {
   sum += *j;
   uint16_t overflow = sum>>16;  //capture the overflow bit, move it back to lsb
   sum &= (1<<16)-1;    //clear the overflow
   sum += overflow;     //add it back as lsb
}
```

Comment: you are right about concatenation of 16bits (two characters at a time) from string entered. you are also correct about the sum part. i want to sum the concatenated 16 bits such that to the first 16 bits of my string i add the next 16 and then the next till the end of my string. But the rule of 16 at a time and string being picked 16 at a time applies! thats important

Comment: i want to save this sum to an approachable place! unfortunately i am not very good with using vectors..but since iv trodden on with it m stuck.

Comment: you really don't need to use vectors at all.  `uint32_t sum = bits + oldbits;  if (sum&0x10000) { //overflow occured.  Do something; } sum&=0x10000;`

Comment: what you've done above, how can i display the final sum for that. and is it the same as what i am tryin to do?

Comment: what are you doing with the overflow exactly, can the final overflow value be added to the binary sum value in this manner 0000000000000001(where 1 is at the 16th bit position). thats what i intend to do....wrap it around to lsb of final sum and add it.

Comment: i dont want to clear the overflow...want to wrap it around to lsb and add to the final sum.

Comment: where exactly is the input string, the one given as input before anything is done to it, where can we take it as input from user and feed it to the code?

Comment: i get it s holds hello.

Comment: that's a whole different question.

Comment: cant we give an input using cin andd getline and take it as an s string?

Comment: std::vector<uint16_t> bitvec; //i am getting an errors of 'uint16_t was not declared in scope' and 'tempelate argument not valid' for this line